# extjs setValue for textfield not working with objects

Tags: javascript, extjs

Quite new to extjs. When I set the value of a textfield with a constant value it works fine. but how can I get the contents of obj as seen here.

This is my json file

```
{ success :true, data :{ event_id:'1',event_type:'we',szdate:'0000-00-00',szvenue:'ww',population:'233',rsvp_name:'Amma Baffoe',rsvp_cont:'222' , event_id:'2',event_type:'',szdate:'0000-00-00',szvenue:'',population:'0',rsvp_name:'Serwaa',rsvp_cont:'' }}
```

This is my code

```
      obj = Ext.JSON.decode(action.responseText);
      Ext.getCmp('population').setValue("I am here"); // works fine
      Ext.getCmp('population').setValue(obj.variable); //how do I get the variable 'szdate'?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
Ext.getCmp('population').setValue(obj.data.szdate);
```

Or if you've got the `szdate` value in a varibale, Like this:

```
var varibale = 'szdate';
Ext.getCmp('population').setValue(obj.data[varibale]);
```

Comment: Does not show when I use setValue(obj.szdate) or setValue(obj[varibale]);

Comment: I get the json file OK but to I want to parse the object to a textfield component

Comment: great. I get it now. thanks. know of any great videos/books for extjs?

Comment: You should follow a tutorial of sencha, this one is good: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/editable_grid